# how to connect to wifi network at boot time using NetworkManager

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and, unless I log in, the server does not connect to the wifi network.

I've found a non-optimal solution/workaround using these steps:

```
 1. Stopping and disabling NetworkManager
 2. Establishing the connection using 'wpa_supplicant'
 3. Getting an IP with 'dhclient'
```

but I couldn't figure out how to do this using NetworkManager, anyone knows how to connect to the wifi network at boot time using NetworkManager?

Any tip/suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here's the output of 'cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml':

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat  /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: When you click the NM icon, do you see networks to connect to? Are there any clues in: `sudo dmesg | grep etwork`

Comment: @chili555, I don't have any problem seeing networks or connecting to them once I'm logged in; the problem is that I have to be logged into the server in order to connect to the wifi .... what I want to achieve is to automatically connect to the wifi network just by turning on the computer without the need to logging in first; I want to use the server remotely ... hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: Then I'd ditch NM and use netplan. May I propose an answer?